# Webscraping w/BeautifulSoup return class value

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I'm starting to learn how to webscrape with BeautifulSoup, and I came across a doubt which I can't seem to overcome.
I'm trying to save each article id and print it however my program always returns nothing. [This is part of the html im using, I want to obtain the value inside data-ad-id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/873dU.png) (in this case 8083037957)

```
for art in soup.find_all('article'):
 values = [regist.text for regist in art.find_all('data-ad-id')]
 data.append(values)
print(values)
```

How can I proceed on this one? Thank you

Comment: Note you should avoid posting pictures and always post the code in text. This way if a future user views your question, there is no worry about the image no longer being hosted

Comment: your code is not indented properly, that might be problem #1

Comment: @Z4-tier I'm just a noob at formatting here sorry

Comment: But I can see that you pasted it that way, so i think what you pasted is incorrect. If you're certain that the site broke it and your code it correct, then please enclose the code in triple-backticks (https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code see the second section where it explains the backtick syntax) and then indent it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something as simple as 'soup.article' may solve your problem!

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(HTML, "lxml") # Replace 'HTML'
values = soup.article['data-ad-id']
data.append(values)
```

Comment: For multiple ids I tried a for loop like : for art in soup.find_all('article'): values = soup.article['data-ad-id'] data.append(values). However it only retrieves one ID per page how can I adapt it? Thanks